# How do I make my images align horizontally instead of vertically inside a column?

Tags: html, css

So here is what I have. I would want the images in the pictures to align under the bigger image above. I'm fairly new to html and css. When I add display flex in css it makes it even worse. I'm confused af. I think it could be the picture's size or something like that.

```
HTML:<div class="small-container single-product">
<div class="row">
    <div class="column2">
        <img src="Produkt1.1.jpg" alt="Produkt" width="70%">
        
        <div class="small-img-row">
            <div class="small-img-col">
                <img src="Produkt1.1.jpg" alt="Produkt" width="20%">
            </div>
            <div class="small-img-col">
                <img src="Produkt1.2.jpg" alt="Produkt" width="20%">
            </div>
            <div class="small-img-col">
                <img src="Produkt1.3.jpg" alt="Produkt" width="20%">
            </div>
        </div>
        
        
    </div>
    <div class="column2">
        <p>Hem / (produkt här)</p>
        <h1>Produkt</h1>
        <h4>123kr</h4>
        
        <select>
            <option>Alternativ</option>
            <option>Alternativ</option>
            <option>Alternativ</option>
            <option>Alternativ</option>
            <option>Alternativ</option>
            <option>Alternativ</option> 
        </select>
        <input type="number" value="1">
        <a href="" class="button">Lägg i vagnen</a>
        
        <h3>Detaljer</h3>
        <hr>
        <p>info om produkten</p>
    </div> 
</div>
```

```
CSS:.single-product{
margin-top: 80px;}.single-product .column2 img{
padding: 0;}.single-product .column2{
padding: 0;}.single-product h4{
margin: 20px 0;
font-size: 22px;
font-weight: bold;}.single-product select{
display: block;
padding: 10px;
margin-top: 20px; }.single-product input{
width: 50px;
height: 40px;
padding-left: 10px;
font-size: 20px;
margin-right: 10px
border: 1px solid #ff523b;}input:focus{
outline: none;}.small-img-row{
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;}.small-img-col{
flex: 32%;
cursor: pointer;}
```

WEBSITE IMAGE:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
a{
text-decoration:none;
}
.single-product{
margin-top: 80px;}.single-product .column2 img{
padding: 0;}.single-product .column2{
padding: 0;}.single-product h4{
margin: 20px 0;
font-size: 22px;
font-weight: bold;}.single-product select{
display: block;
padding: 10px;
margin-top: 20px; }.single-product input{
width: 50px;
height: 40px;
padding-left: 10px;
font-size: 20px;
margin-right: 10px
border: 1px solid #ff523b;}input:focus{
outline: none;}.small-img-row{
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;}.small-img-col{
flex: 32%;
cursor: pointer;}
.small-img-row{
width:100%;
margin:5px 0;
}
table{
width:100%;
}

table td{
width:45%;
padding:30px;
}
.column2,.row{
width:100%;
}
.small-img-col{
width:32%;
margin:0 0.5%;
}
.button{
padding:10px 20px;
border-radius:20px;
outline:none;
color:#fff;
background:#3399ff;
text-align:center;
border:0;
}
select{
display:block;
margin:10px 0;
}

@media (max-width:720px){
table td{
display:block;
width:95%;
padding:15px;
}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="small-container single-product">
<table class="row">
<tr>
<td>
<div class="column2">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2pwD.png" alt="Produkt" width="100%">
<div class="small-img-row">
<div class="small-img-col">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2pwD.png" alt="Produkt" width="100%">
</div>
<div class="small-img-col">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2pwD.png" alt="Produkt" width="100%">
</div>
<div class="small-img-col">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2pwD.png" alt="Produkt" width="100%">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td>

<div class="column2">
<p>Hem / (produkt här)</p>
<h1>Produkt</h1>
<h4>123kr</h4>
<select>
<option>Alternativ</option>
<option>Alternativ</option>
<option>Alternativ</option>
<option>Alternativ</option>
<option>Alternativ</option>
<option>Alternativ</option> 
</select>
<input type="number" value="1">
<a href="" class="button">Lägg i vagnen</a>
<h3>Detaljer</h3>
<hr>
<p>info om produkten</p>
</div>
</td>
</tr> 
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```